# Does TCP guarantee packet transmission time?

Tags: networking

This is a review question but I can't find anything in my book about it. What I did find online is contradictory and confusing.

Comment: best effort only, it can't help if the IP layer can't deliver.

Comment: You can run TCP over avian carrier if you wanted to (you can run IP over it - you can run TCP on top of that).

Comment: [RFC 2549 IP over Avian Carriers with Quality of Service](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2549)

Answer (score 8):

No, TCP will time out and request that a packet be re-sent, but there's no guaranteed transit time. TCP (typically) relies on IP, which can dynamically route packets, so there's no way to estimate how long it will/should take.

Answer (score 3):

TCP cannot promise delivery, but it can guarantee that either the packet will be delivered and acknowledged within a timeout (4 minutes IIRC), or you will get an error response. (Which, come to think of it, is what the word "guarantee" usually means: if the promised action does not occur, you will have some remedy available. A guarantee on a hard drive doesn't mean it won't fail; it means that if it fails you can get a replacement or your money back.)

In the sense of "*guarantee* means unbreakable promise", nothing is ever guaranteed. In the sense of "*guarantee* = *warranty*", then yes, TCP guarantees delivery.